# GCP - Deny Permissions for Specific Resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, identity-management

How do I set up explicit deny permissions for a specific resource in GCP? For example, I have 2 GKE clusters in my project, say "dev-gke" and "qa-gke". How do I ensure that folks in the team are denied permission to update/delete the "qa-gke" cluster while they can continue to do so on the "ts-dev" cluster.

I contemplated setting up a deny policy as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-overview) using `denialCondition` and `resource.matchTag` referencing a tag for "ts-qa" cluster.

```
  "denialCondition": {
      "title":  "QA Setup",
      "expression": "resource.matchTag('12345678/env', 'ts-qa')"
```

But as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-overview?_ga=2.243480837.-1813820426.1656354117#tags_and_labels) tags are defined at an organization level and not at a resource level. And, I couldn't find out an equivalent of `resource.matchTag` for labels.

Comment: Did you check RBAC https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control ?

Answer (score 1):

With not having any suitable way to address this from IAM permissions itself, I ended up creating `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` for the clusters individually with respective users who should be allowed to have access.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control

Answer (score 0):

see this doc https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-access.

And probably you may use IAM tag to attach tag to your clusters, also see this https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-creating-and-managing#gcloud_8.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question, I have considered this option but was unable to use tags as they are defined at an organization level and I need a way to get this done at my project level.